# Как сделать поиск по буквам, как в записной книжке?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать поиск, как в записной книжке Самсунг? Нажатие на буквы справа и переход к соответствующей букве на экране. Как это сделать? Интересует `UI` и техническая часть. Я так понимаю, что для колонки справа (алфавита) можно использовать `RecyclerView`, к нему добавить `OnClickListener`. Контакты тоже можно поместить в `RecyclerView` или `ExpandableListView` и при нажатии справа скролить к определенной позиции контактов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно вам помогут готовые примеры: [AlphabetScroll](https://github.com/viethoa/recyclerview-alphabet-fast-scroller-android) и [Alphabet RecyclerView](https://github.com/myinnos/AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView)/ Может вам достаточно будет и этих уже готовых библиотек

Comment: Если будете делать свою реализацию, напишите ответ, как там что, если будет возможность.

Comment: Если будете делать свою реализацию, посмотрите сначала готовые реализации,  чтобы с нуля не писать :).

Comment: слишком широкий вопрос, в записной книжке разные решение в разных версиях Android не говоря уже о множестве  device имеющих свои оболочки поверх, HTC, LG, MeizU, Huawei, Zeta, Asus да блин почти у всех есть свои решения, поэтому что вам надо. Так как нативное решение выглядит иначе, я могу дать ответ только боюсь потратить время зря. Если вы имеете ввиду Google Contacts, то тогда друге дело, то что у вас на скрине отличается, у меня такая штука была на 4.03 LG. Уточните я с радостью покажу как это сделать

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Мне нужно то, что на картинке, так записная книжка выглядит в Samsung, мне нужно сделать такой же поиск в приложении. Имена (контакты) будут приходить с сервера и будут храниться в локальной БД.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul id="myUL">
  <div class="ing" id="ing" 
     onclick="fg()">

    <li><a href="#" id="gb">Авокадо 

    <li><a href="#">Ананас</a>.</li>

    <li><a href="#">Апельсин</a>.</li>
 </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("searching");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
function fg() {
  let j = document.getElementById("ing");
  document.querySelector("#ing").onclick = (even) => {
  let f = even.target;
  document.querySelector("#searching").value = f.textContent;
  f.style.boxShadow = "3px 3px grey";
  setTimeout(function() {
    f.style.boxShadow = "10px 10px grey";
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Теги "Java" и "Android" в вопросе как бы намекают, что такое решение не очень то подойдет